# Different Icon for EXE and file

Tags: python, file

Hey I've made a text editor using wx and compiled using pyinstaller! The icon of the file is:[image]

But now If I make it my default editor for Text files, the icon of all text files becomes this...How do I make the icon of the text files and the icon for the EXE different? I mean look at visual studio code:[image]

It's different. So where am I supposed to change? In wx ( main code ) or pyinstaller ( while turning it into an EXE )? Also, how? Any help will be appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if there is a proper way to do this, but...

You could have multiple executables with different icons that just launch the editor, passing through the command-line arguments.